# Get more speed in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I wrote this code to get the stock market data and after getting the data, I save it in the Mongo database, then I get the required data from the Mongo database and convert it into a dataframe.
Using the data in the rows, I calculate the values I need. This operation takes about 35 seconds. I need this operation to be done in the shortest possible time, the less the better.
Thank you for your guidance

```
%%time
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import math
import requests
import pandas as pd
import jdatetime
import json
import time
import pymongo

start = time.time()

client = pymongo.MongoClient()

database = client['raw']
cursor = database.list_collection_names()
cursor.sort()`your text`
Raw = database[cursor[-1]]

data = pd.DataFrame(Raw.find())
df = data[["tse_url", "l18", "l30", 'pc', 'pl', 'tno', 'tvol', 'tval', 'py', 'stock']]

option = df.loc[df['stock'].isin(['311', '312', '320', '321'])]


db = client['transaction']
dbCol = db.list_collection_names()
dbCol.sort()
Trans = db[dbCol[-1]]
trans = pd.DataFrame(Trans.find({}, {"tse_url", "row", "buy", 'sell'}))
trans = trans.drop('_id',axis=1)
trans = trans.loc[trans['row'] == '1']


binazir = client['binazir']
lst = binazir.list_collection_names()
lst.sort()
latest = binazir[lst[-1]]
OC = pd.DataFrame(latest.find({}, {"tse_url", "open_positions", "contract_size"}))


option.insert(3, 'contract', '')
option.insert(3, 'blackscholes', '')
option.insert(3, 'open', '')
option.insert(3, '%t', '')
option.insert(3, 'through', '')
option.insert(3, '%pc', '')
option.insert(3, '%pl', '')
option.insert(3, 's1', '')
option.insert(3, 'b1', '')
option.insert(3, 'mature', '')
option.insert(3, 'status', '')
option.insert(3, 'bp', '')
option.insert(3, 'strike', '')
option.insert(3, 'volatility', '')
option.insert(3, 'SellBS', '')
option.insert(3, 'BuyBS', '')
option.insert(3, 'lever', '')
option.insert(3, 'delta', '')
option.insert(3, 'deltaLever', '')
option.insert(3, 'vega', '')
option.insert(3, 'theta', '')
option.insert(3, 'gamma', '')
option.insert(3, 'rho', '')
option.insert(3, 'margin', '')
option.insert(3, 'undif', '')

for a in zip(option['tse_url'], option.index):
    for b in zip(trans['tse_url'], trans['buy'], trans['sell']):
        if a[0] == b[0]:
            option.at[a[1], 's1'] = b[2]
            option.at[a[1], 'b1'] = b[1]

for a in zip(option['l30'], option.index):
    x = a[0].split('-')
    option.at[a[1], 'strike'] = x[1]
    namad = x[0][8:]
    if x[2].startswith('00'):
        date = x[2].replace('00', '1400')
    elif x[2].startswith('01'):
        date = x[2].replace('01', '1401')
    else:
        date = x[2]
    if date[4] == '/':
        today = jdatetime.datetime.strptime(jdatetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d")
        mature = (jdatetime.datetime.strptime((date.replace('/', '')), "%Y%m%d") - today).days
        option.at[a[1], 'mature'] = mature
    else:
        today = jdatetime.datetime.strptime(jdatetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d")
        mature = (jdatetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d") - today).days
        option.at[a[1], 'mature'] = mature
    x = namad.replace("هم‌وزن", "هم وزن")
    y = x.replace("حافرين", "حآفرين")
    z = y.replace("ص.دارا", "دارا")

    for d in zip(data['l18'], data['pc'], data['tse_url']):
        if z == d[0]:
            option.at[a[1], 'bp'] = d[1]
            option.at[a[1], 'StockName'] = z
            option.at[a[1], 'StockURL'] = d[2]

for a in zip(option['bp'], option['strike'], option['stock'], option.index):
    if a[2] == '311' or a[2] == '320':
        if int(a[0]) > int(a[1]):
            option.at[a[3], 'status'] = 'ITM'
        elif int(a[0]) < int(a[1]):
            option.at[a[3], 'status'] = 'OTM'
        else:
            option.at[a[3], 'status'] = 'ATM'
    else:
        if int(a[0]) < int(a[1]):
            option.at[a[3], 'status'] = 'ITM'
        elif int(a[0]) > int(a[1]):
            option.at[a[3], 'status'] = 'OTM'
        else:
            option.at[a[3], 'status'] = 'ATM'

for a in zip(option['pl'], option['strike'], option['s1'], option.index, option['bp'], option['stock']):
    if a[5] == '311' or a[5] == '320':
        if a[2] == '0':
            t = (int(a[0]) + int(a[1]))
            option.at[a[3], 'through'] = t
        else:
            t = (int(a[2]) + int(a[1]))
            option.at[a[3], 'through'] = t
    else:
        if a[2] == '0':
            t = (int(a[1]) - int(a[0]))
            option.at[a[3], 'through'] = t
        else:
            t = (int(a[1]) - int(a[2]))
            option.at[a[3], 'through'] = t

    pt = (t - int(a[4])) / int(a[4]) * 100
    option.at[a[3], '%t'] = round(pt, 2)




for a in zip(option['tse_url'], option.index):
    for b in zip(OC['tse_url'],OC["open_positions"], OC["contract_size"]):
        if a[0] == b[0]:
            option.at[a[1], 'open'] = b[1]
            option.at[a[1], 'contract'] = b[2]
        else:
            option.at[a[1], 'open'] = 0
            option.at[a[1], 'contract'] = 1000


for a in zip(option['pl'], option['pc'], option['py'], option.index):
    option.at[a[3], '%pl'] = round((int(a[0]) - int(a[2])) / int(a[2]) * 100, 2)
    option.at[a[3], '%pc'] = round((int(a[1]) - int(a[2])) / int(a[2]) * 100, 2)


_list = set()
for a in zip(option['StockURL']):
    _list.add(a[0])

for b in _list:
    col = {
        0: 'ticker',
        1: 'date',
        2: 'first',
        3: 'high',
        4: 'low',
        5: 'close',
        6: 'value',
        7: 'vol',
        8: 'openint',
        9: 'per',
        10: 'open',
        11: 'last',
    }
    url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/Export-txt.aspx?t=i&a=1&b=0&i=%s' % str(b)
    r = requests.get(url)
    main_text = r.text
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in main_text.split('\r\n')]).drop(0, axis=0)
    data = df.rename(columns=col)
    dd = data.drop(['ticker',
                    'date',
                    'first',
                    'high',
                    'low',
                    'value',
                    'vol',
                    'openint',
                    'per',
                    'open',
                    'last', ], axis=1)

    dd['close'] = dd['close'].astype('float')
    dd.at[dd.index, 'closen'] = dd['close'].shift(-1).astype('float')
    for i in zip(dd['close'], dd['closen'], dd.index):
        ln = 100 * math.log(i[0] / i[1])
        dd.at[i[2], 'ln'] = ln
    dd.drop(dd.loc[dd['ln'] >= 10].index, inplace=True)
    dd.drop(dd.loc[dd['ln'] <= -10].index, inplace=True)
    cc = dd.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
    ff = cc.iloc[:132]
    volatility = (np.std(ff['ln'], ddof=1)) * math.sqrt(245)
    for p in zip(option['StockURL'], option.index):
        if p[0] == b:
            option.at[p[1], 'volatility'] = round(volatility, 1)




for a in zip(option['strike'], option['bp'], option['mature'], option['volatility'], option['stock'], option.index,option['pl'], option['s1']):
    S = int(a[1])
    K = int(a[0])
    T = int(a[2])
    r = 0.25
    sigma = float(a[3]) / 100
    q = 0
    if T == 0:
        d1 = 0
    else:
        d1 = (math.log(S / K) + ((r - q + (0.5 * (sigma ** 2))) * T / 365)) / (sigma * math.sqrt(T / 365))

    d2 = (d1 - sigma * math.sqrt(T / 365))

    if T == 0:
        t1 = 0
    else:
        t1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r + sigma**2/2)* T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    t2 = d1 - sigma * np.sqrt(T)

    Nd1 = math.exp(-(d1**2) / 2)/math.sqrt(2*3.14)
    option.at[a[5], 'gamma'] = round(Nd1 * math.exp(-q*T)/S*sigma*T**0.5)
    option.at[a[5], 'vega'] = round(S*T**0.5*Nd1)
    if a[2] == 0 and K >= S:
        option.at[a[5], 'blackscholes'] = 0
    elif a[2] == 0 and K < S:
        option.at[a[5], 'blackscholes'] = S - K
    else:
        if a[4] == '311' or a[4] == '320':
            call = (S * math.exp(-q * T / 365) * norm.cdf(d1) - K * math.exp(-r * T / 365) * norm.cdf(d2))
            deltaCall = norm.cdf(d1)
            option.at[a[5], 'blackscholes'] = round(call)
            option.at[a[5], 'delta'] = round(deltaCall, 4)
            option.at[a[5], 'rho'] = round(K*T*math.exp(-r*T)*norm.cdf(d2), 4)
            option.at[a[5], 'theta'] = round(1/365*(-(S*sigma*math.exp(-q*T)*Nd1/2*T**0.5)-r*K*math.exp(-r*T)*norm.cdf(d2)+q*S*math.exp(-q*T)*norm.cdf(d1)), 4)
            if int(a[7]) == 0:
                option.at[a[5], 'deltaLever'] = round(S*deltaCall - int(a[6])/int(a[6]),2)
            else:
                option.at[a[5], 'deltaLever'] = round(S*deltaCall - int(a[7])/int(a[7]),2)

        else:
            put = (K * math.exp(-r * T / 365) * norm.cdf(-1 * d2) - S * math.exp(-q * T / 365) * norm.cdf(-1 * d1))
            deltaPut = norm.cdf(d1)-1
            option.at[a[5], 'blackscholes'] = round(put)
            option.at[a[5], 'delta'] = round(deltaPut, 4)
            option.at[a[5], 'rho'] = round(-K*T*math.exp(-r*T)*norm.cdf(-d2), 4)
            option.at[a[5], 'theta'] = round(1/365*(-(S*sigma*math.exp(-q*T)*Nd1/2*T**0.5)+r*K*math.exp(-r*T)*norm.cdf(-d2)-q*S*math.exp(-q*T)*norm.cdf(-d1)), 4)
            if int(a[7]) == 0:
                option.at[a[5], 'deltaLever'] = round(S*deltaPut - int(a[6])/int(a[6]),2)
            else:
                option.at[a[5], 'deltaLever'] = round(S*deltaPut - int(a[7])/int(a[7]),2)



for a in zip(option['s1'], option['blackscholes'], option['pl'], option.index):
    if int(a[0]) == 0 and int(a[1]) == 0:
        option.at[a[3], 'SellBS'] = 0
    elif int(a[0]) == 0 and int(a[1]) != 0:
        option.at[a[3], 'SellBS'] = "بدون فروشنده"
    elif int(a[0]) != 0 and int(a[1]) == 0:
        option.at[a[3], 'SellBS'] = round(int(a[0]) * 100, 2)
    else:
        option.at[a[3], 'SellBS'] = round(((int(a[0]) - int(a[1])) / int(a[1])) * 100, 2)

for a in zip(option['b1'], option['blackscholes'], option['pl'], option.index):
    if int(a[0]) == 0 and int(a[1]) == 0:
        option.at[a[3], 'BuyBS'] = 0
    elif int(a[0]) == 0 and int(a[1]) != 0:
        option.at[a[3], 'BuyBS'] = "بدون خریدار"
    elif int(a[0]) != 0 and int(a[1]) == 0:
        option.at[a[3], 'BuyBS'] = round(int(a[0]) * 100, 2)
    else:
        option.at[a[3], 'BuyBS'] = round(((int(a[0]) - int(a[1])) / int(a[1])) * 100, 2)
for a in zip(option['s1'], option['strike'], option['pl'], option.index):
    if int(a[0]) == 0:
        option.at[a[3], 'lever'] = round((int(a[1]) / int(a[2])), 2)
    else:
        option.at[a[3], 'lever'] = round((int(a[1]) / int(a[0])), 2)

for a in zip(option['strike'], option['bp'], option['stock'], option.index,option['pl'], option['s1'], option['contract']):
    if a[2] == '311' or a[2] == '320':
        l =  abs(min(int(a[1]) - int(a[0]), 0)) * int(a[6])
        I1 = 0.2 * int(a[1]) * int(a[6]) - l
        I2 = 0.1 * int(a[0]) * int(a[6])
        V1 = (math.floor(max(I1, I2) / 100000) + 1) * 100000
        if a[5] != '0':
            V2 = int(a[5]) * int(a[6])
            M = V1 + V2
            option.at[a[3],'margin']=round(M)
            option.at[a[3],'undif']= round(int(a[0])/int(a[5])-int(a[1]) - 1, 4)*100
        else:
            V2 = int(a[4]) * int(a[6])
            M = V1 + V2
            option.at[a[3],'margin']=round(M)
            option.at[a[3],'undif']= round(int(a[0])/int(a[4])-int(a[1]) - 1, 4)*100
    else:
        l =  abs(int(a[0]) - min(int(a[1]), 0)) * int(a[6])
        I1 = 0.2 * int(a[1]) * int(a[6]) - l
        I2 = 0.1 * int(a[0]) * int(a[6])
        V1 = (math.floor(max(I1, I2) / 100000) + 1) * 100000
        if a[5] != '0':
            V2 = int(a[5]) * int(a[6])
            M = V1 + V2
            option.at[a[3],'margin']=round(M)
            option.at[a[3],'undif']= round(int(a[0])/int(a[5])-int(a[1]) - 1, 4)*100

        else:
            V2 = int(a[4]) * int(a[6])
            M = V1 + V2
            option.at[a[3],'margin']=round(M)
            option.at[a[3],'undif']= round(int(a[0])/int(a[4])-int(a[1]) - 1, 4)*100




end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

I need to reduce the execution time of this code to the lowest possible time, but currently it takes about 35 seconds.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Briefly looking at your MongoDB related code and what is later done with the retrieved data, it seems much of returned data is thrown away or filtered.  You could do more filtering and projecting with a more targeted MongoDB query.

Comment: Rather than a long sequence of `option.insert(...`, might it be faster to create a new dataframe using `pd.concat`?

Comment: Why not `_list = set(option['StockURL'])` instead of zipping/looping/extraction?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is slow because of all those loops.  It is way outside the scope of a single question and answer to actually fix all that code, but I can tell you how to fix it:

1. Profile each part.  Break the code down into steps, perhaps into functions or just time each outer loop.  This will tell you where to spend your time optimizing.
2. Figure out how to use Pandas and NumPy in a "vectorized" way.  This means instead of looping over each row of a DataFrame, find an equivalent operation you can apply to all rows at once.  For example if you need to multiply one column by another, just say `df['A'] * df['B']` to get the entire resulting series at once, instead of using a `for` loop to populate one cell at a time.  By using vectorized operations, your program will mostly execute compiled library code which is highly optimized, rather than slow Python code.
3. If there is a part which is not amenable to vectorization, use Numba.  Numba is a just-in-time compiler for NumPy, and it can wrap a Python function into a callable object which compiles the code the first time it's called so that it will execute as quickly as possible (as if you wrote the code in C or C++, in some cases).
4. Walk before you run.  Isolate the smallest piece of your code which takes a significant amount of time, put its inputs into a text file so you can easily reload them, and experiment.  Don't try to optimize the entire program at once, if it takes 35 seconds every time you try something, you'll never finish.  Separating your code into well-defined functions will help.